# Firebase: passing data to cloudfunction results in: Object cannot be encoded in JSON

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I try to call a cloud function and pass some data. My data is of type `Map<String, Object>` and inside it has again some nested `Map<String, Object>`. When trying to call my function with this:

```
getHttpsCallable(function).call(data)...
```

I get this error:

```
Cloud Function Exception:                                                         
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object cannot be encoded in JSON: [Ljava.util.Map;@42896770
 at com.google.firebase.functions.Serializer.encode(Serializer.java:136)
 at com.google.firebase.functions.Serializer.encode(Serializer.java:77)
 at com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctions.call(FirebaseFunctions.java:255)
 at com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctions.access$100(FirebaseFunctions.java:34)
 at com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctions$2.then(FirebaseFunctions.java:233)
 at com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctions$2.then(FirebaseFunctions.java:225)
 at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzd.run(Unknown Source)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When printing my data object it looks like this:

```
{items=[Ljava.util.Map;@42896770, element1=OzNGHzHeq6av03hRmMJ6, time=Sun May 05 04:40:00 MEZ 3918}
```

**I tried the following:**
I tried packing an array instead of a Map inside my data-object. => Did not work.

I tried to convert my data into a json myself and send it, this also didn't work.

I did the follwoing:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String dataJSON = gson.toJson(data);
```

which restulted in a nice formatted JSON:

```
{"items":[{"count":1,"itemId":"94To3bKnxoWzayLdy55I"},{"count":3,"itemId":"fkNtIUxbfg5GhLJy2Dma"},{"count":1,"itemId":"sDYTp7cpQTRfWuI6CSaK"},{"count":1,"itemId":"qGGl5U0qihHnMzhBMjyb","options":["2.0","1.0","1.1","0.0"]},{"count":1,"itemId":"qGGl5U0qihHnMzhBMjyb","options":["2.0","1.0","1.1","0.1"]},{"count":1,"itemId":"qGGl5U0qihHnMzhBMjyb","options":["2.0","1.0","1.1","0.2"]},{"count":1,"itemId":"qGGl5U0qihHnMzhBMjyb","options":["2.3","1.0","1.1","0.1"]}],"storeId":"OzNGHzHeq6av03hRmMJ6","pickupTime":"May 5, 3918 4:40:00 AM"}
```

But I also tried to call my function with a hardcoded JSON which did not work either.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Does anyone know?

Comment: Maybe use the Gson library https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/ or https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I did. I used it in my approach to send a prebuild json.

Comment: `{items=[Ljava.util.Map;@42896770,...` does not look at JSON...

Comment: yes. It looks like this, when just trying what I am talking about in my initial question-text. I just told in my question that I also tried some other stuff, including generating a json with gson.

Comment: Can you share the code you have written with Gson to transform your java object in JSON?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec: Please see my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170232/discussion-between-renaud-tarnec-and-prognewbie).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are actually passing `array` of `Map` objects.

As Frederik Byl shows the source code of Functions SDK for Android, it won't accept array type. It accepts `Map` or `List` Java Collection object.

So you must change your `[Ljava.util.Map;` to `List<Map>` type.

Plus, actully Firestore uses [Protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3) for core dataset. You can find more information at [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#json) how they encode or decode json with Protobuf data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create and pass a JSONObject out of your data object. Not a string or the data object:
like this:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
    String jsonString = gson.toJson(data);
    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
    try {
         jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

because:

```
  public Object encode(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null && obj != JSONObject.NULL) {
        JSONObject result;
        if (obj instanceof Long) {
            result = new JSONObject();

            try {
                result.put("@type", "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Int64Value");
                result.put("value", obj.toString());
                return result;
            } catch (JSONException var9) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error encoding Long.", var9);
            }
        } else if (obj instanceof Number) {
            return obj;
        } else if (obj instanceof String) {
            return obj;
        } else if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
            return obj;
        } else if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
            return obj;
        } else if (obj instanceof JSONArray) {
            return obj;
        } else {
            Object o;
            String key;
            Object value;
            Iterator keys;
            if (obj instanceof Map) {
                result = new JSONObject();
                Map<?, ?> m = (Map)obj;
                keys = m.keySet().iterator();

                while(keys.hasNext()) {
                    o = keys.next();
                    if (!(o instanceof String)) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object keys must be strings.");
                    }

                    key = (String)o;
                    value = this.encode(m.get(o));

                    try {
                        result.put(key, value);
                    } catch (JSONException var10) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(var10);
                    }
                }

                return result;
            } else {
                JSONArray result;
                if (obj instanceof List) {
                    result = new JSONArray();
                    List<?> l = (List)obj;
                    keys = l.iterator();

                    while(keys.hasNext()) {
                        o = keys.next();
                        result.put(this.encode(o));
                    }

                    return result;
                } else {
                    JSONObject wrapped;
                    if (obj instanceof JSONObject) {
                        result = new JSONObject();
                        wrapped = (JSONObject)obj;
                        keys = wrapped.keys();

                        while(keys.hasNext()) {
                            String k = (String)keys.next();
                            if (!(k instanceof String)) {
                                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object keys must be strings.");
                            }

                            key = k;
                            value = this.encode(wrapped.opt(k));

                            try {
                                result.put(key, value);
                            } catch (JSONException var11) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(var11);
                            }
                        }

                        return result;
                    } else if (!(obj instanceof JSONArray)) {
                        if (obj instanceof Date) {
                            String utc = this.dateFormat.format((Date)obj);
                            wrapped = new JSONObject();

                            try {
                                wrapped.put("@type", "type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Timestamp");
                                wrapped.put("value", utc);
                                return wrapped;
                            } catch (JSONException var12) {
                                throw new RuntimeException("Error encoding Date.", var12);
                            }
                        } else {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Object cannot be encoded in JSON: " + obj);
                        }
                    } else {
                        result = new JSONArray();
                        JSONArray l = (JSONArray)obj;

                        for(int i = 0; i < l.length(); ++i) {
                            o = l.opt(i);
                            result.put(this.encode(o));
                        }

                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing a `org.json.JSONObject` instead of the `com.google.gson.JsonObject` works just fine.

You don't need to use Maps on the firebase functions.